# Save an image in matplotlib which is both square (n_pixel x n_pixel) and without padding

Tags: python, matplotlib, padding, pixel

I want to save an image as a square (having the same number of pixels in the 2 dimensions corresponding to `n_pixel` x `n_pixel`). I also want it to be saved without any padding on the side. For this, the following code saves the image (288x288 pixels), but there is padding (in red).

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 400)
y = np.sin(x ** 2)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(4,4))
ax.set_ylim(-1, 1)
ax.axis('off')
ax.plot(x,y)
fig.savefig("try.png",                   
            #pad_inches=-0.2
            #bbox_inches='tight'
           )
plt.close(fig)
```

[image]

Now, uncommenting the line with `#bbox_inches='tight'` saves the image without the padding but the saved image is now 237x231 pixels

[image]

How to save the image squared without padding?

**EDIT**
Thanks to the answer of @fdireito, after adding `fig.subplots_adjust(left=0, right=1, bottom=0, top=1)` here is the code that solve both constraints

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 400)
y = np.sin(x ** 2)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(4,4))
ax.set_ylim(-1, 1)
ax.axis('off')
ax.plot(x,y)

fig.subplots_adjust(left=0, right=1, bottom=0, top=1)
fig.savefig("try.png",                   
            #pad_inches=-0.2
            bbox_inches='tight'
           )
plt.close(fig)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To remove the padding you mention, you can use:

```
fig.subplots_adjust(left=0, right=1, bottom=0, top=1)
```

The numbers above, refer to relative positions of the figure. So, if you set top to 0.5 instead of 1,

```
fig.subplots_adjust(left=0, right=1, bottom=0, top=0.5)
```

you will get something like this:

[image]

This is, the subplots will, on the left, be at position 0 of the figure, at 1 (max) of the figure on the right, and at 0 in the bottom. Because, in this case, top is set to 0.5, then the top of your curve goes half way in the vertical direction.

See [here](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplots_adjust.html).

By the way, you may need to set x limits, as well:

```
ax.set_xlim(min(x),max(x))
```

Comment: Many thanks for your answer @fdireito. That solved the problem